# Why UICollectionView stops working when NSMutableAttributedString is set to one of its cells

Tags: uicollectionview, uitextview

I stumbled upon a special problem in my current project.

We have `UICollectionView` using a custom layout called [SquareMosaicLayout](https://github.com/iwheelbuy/SquareMosaicLayout).
Within this collection view the first cell it presenting a `UITextView`.

This text view again shall show an html text created with:

`NSMutableAttributedString(fromHTMLString: htmlString, textColor: textColor, font: font)`

Now when this string is assigned to the text view the collection view somehow stops working which means it does not ask the datasource for new cells when scrolling through the collection view.

This results in the collection view showing blank space.

Unfortunately I did not have time to isolate the problem in terms of if the custom layout breaks anything but it definitely has to do with assigning the string. If we don't do that the collection view works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

We still did not found the reason for the behaviour but a first workaround.

It is possible to set the `NSMutableAttributedString` asynchronously.

```swift
extension UITextView {

[ ... ]

DispatchQueue.main.async {
     let optionalAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(fromHTMLString: htmlString, textColor: self.textColor, font: self.font)
     guard let attributedText = optionalAttributedText else { return }
     self.attributedText = attributedText

[ ... ]
```

In that case the `UICollectionView` behaves normal showing all the cells.